# SwiftUI Picker in Form does not show checkmark from CoreData

Tags: core-data, swiftui, picker

I have an issue, after selecting a Value in a Picker, I do not see it as selected:

```
struct SampleView: View {
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: Category.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Category.title, ascending: true)
        ]

    ) var categories: FetchedResults<Category>
    @State private var category = UUID()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Form {
                Picker(selection: $category, label: Text("Picker")) {
                    ForEach(categories) { cat in
                        Text(cat.title!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

My Core Data has this two properties:

```
@NSManaged public var title: String?
@NSManaged public var id: UUID?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selection in `Picker`should be the same type as presented values, so you need something like

```
@State private var category: UUID? = UUID()
```

*Note:* probably its due to not all code provided by in my example I needed to change your code as follows to make it compilable (tested with Xcode 11.2)

```
ForEach(categories, id: \.id) { cat in
```

Comment: You made my day, the UUID? solved the problem. Thank you so much!